# How to use the getAssignedPartition() in kafka spring? And what does it give us?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to get the currently assigned partition in Kafka spring, and I found the getAssignedPartition() method, but I couldn't use it properly, how can I use this properly?

For more information: Can I get the information that which partition is going to receive the next message or what partition get the message last?

https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.3.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/kafka/listener/MessageListenerContainer.html#getAssignedPartitions--

Comment: `>but I couldn't use it properly,` It is not clear what that means; explain further - what problems did you have? No, you cannot determine which partition will be used for the next record; you can track yourself from which partition the last record was retrieved.

Comment: Why exactly do you care what partition gets an event? All partitions should be treated equally